# WordPress Static Pages and Django Project

Tags: django, wordpress, amazon-route53

I have a live Django project with static pages for the homepage page and other pages. It is hosted on AWS

Now I have new static pages built in WordPress and I want to be able to use my current domain hosted by AWS to point to use the WordPress static pages I have.

UPDATE:
Django also has other URLs for the app using the same domain. So I want to use the static pages in WordPress but starting from Login page into the app, I want to use the Django templates.

Is this possible?

Comment: It sounds like you just need to change the DocumentRoot in your httpd.conf Apache configuration file.

Comment: Thank you @paulsm4. Can you share more detail about the edits I would have to make and how it works?